# How to Install Sublime Text 3 using Homebrew cask

Tags: sublimetext2, homebrew, sublimetext, sublimetext3, homebrew-cask

How can I use Homebrew cask to install Sublime Text 3? I only see Sublime Text 2 when using Homebrew's search. I even tried tapping [homebrew/versions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions), but no luck.

Comment: Why isn't 3 the default in the normal cask. So weird

Comment: You might want to change the accepted answer since the answer has changed. @frizkie has provided the new procedure, which funny enough is the same as the downvoted answer that was accepted.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As of late May, 2021, Sublime Text 4 has been released. As a result, the old solution to installing Sublime Text 3 via Homebrew will now install Sublime Text 4 instead. If this is what you actually want, then the following `brew` installation command will install  it:

```sh
brew install --cask sublime-text
```

Currently, there is no available cask on Homebrew which will allow the installation of Sublime Text 3 instead of Sublime Text 4.

As a side note, Sublime Text 2 is available in the `sublime-text2` cask.

---

Historical note: This question originally was motivated by the fact that the `sublime-text` cask was Sublime Text 2 instead of Sublime Text 3. As of around May 2016, this is no longer the case.

Comment: Yes, as of [this](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/commit/f577fe715cf73e03d1316c202be1db266682506c) commit, sublime text 3 is now the default.

Comment: then use Caskroom/versions/sublime-text2

Comment: Or for newer versions of brew use: `brew install --cask sublime-text`.

Comment: @rfreytag Of course, updating my answer. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 189):

```
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install sublime-text
```

Weird how I will struggle with this for days, post on StackOverflow, then figure out my own answer in 20 seconds.

[edited to reflect that the package name is now just `sublime-text`, not `sublime-text3`]

[edit]: As of 2022-11-07, above is incorrect.

See taylorthurlow's correct answer.

Comment: Cannot find cask _sublime-text3_ on my machine, only _sublime-text_, which is 2.0.2 now.

Comment: Actually needed this tap: caskroom/versions

Comment: Thanks. Also, for what it's worth, you can tap and install in one command like this: `brew cask install caskroom/versions/sublime-text3`

Comment: Ok, but you need the "cask" plugin before : `brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask`

Comment: caskroom.io has all instructions u need ;)

Comment: Sidenote: if you try this and get the error **"Error: Cask 'sublime-text3' definition is invalid: Bad header line: parse failed"**, run `brew uninstall --force brew-cask && brew update` then retry.

Comment: Sublime text is 3114 now. So the last step should be replaced with brew cask install sublime-text

Comment: Try `brew cask install sublime-text` when getting `No available Cask for sublime-test3.`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also, as other comments state, the last line should be `brew cask install sublime-text`.

Answer (score 37):

**An update**

Turns out now `brew cask install sublime-text` installs the most up to date version (e.g. 3) by default and `brew cask` is now part of the standard `brew`-installation.

Answer (score 16):

```
$ brew tap caskroom/cask
$ brew install brew-cask
$ brew tap caskroom/versions
$ brew cask install sublime-text
```

Comment: Doesn't work unless you run `brew tap caskroom/versions` too.

Comment: Yes jsalonen, you are right, I will update my answer. Thank you

Comment: `$ brew install brew-cask` warns `You must uninstall this formula. It is no longer needed to stay up to date, as Homebrew now takes care of that automatically.`

Answer (score 5):

I did not have `brew cask` installed so I had to install it first,so these were the steps I followed:

```
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install sublime-text
```

Answer (score 5):

Edit: The command will now install version 4 instead of 3

To install Sublime Text <strike>3</strike> **4** run:

```
brew install --cask sublime-text
```

reference: https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/sublime-text

Answer (score 4):

As per latest updates, caskroom packages have moved to homebrew. So try following commands:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask
brew cask install sublime-text
```

These 2 terminal commands will be enough for installing sublime.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that `brew cask <command>` was deprecated in favor of brew `<command> --cask` in Homebrew `2.6.0`. So as of 2021, you can use:

```
brew install --cask sublime-text
```

Comment: Above is the correct answer as of 2022-11-07.

Answer (score 1):

As of 12-12-2022 I have just installed sublime-text using:

```
brew install sublime-text
```

No issue with working with sublime after the installation. Have just checked this. So I am not sure if you need 'cask' anymore.