# How to used Mac OSX -bash command to run sublimetext

Tags: macos, bash, sublimetext3

As the name suggested.
I would like to have something like:

```
sublime ./My_project/my_example.cpp
```

Then it opens the my_example.cpp in SublimeText for me.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is explained [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html).

Basically you just need to create a symbolic link (`ln -s`) somewhere in your path and make it point to the "subl" (not "sublime") executable.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime text includes a command line script `subl` but you'll need to link it into your `/usr/local/bin`

```
ln -s '/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' /usr/local/bin
```

(and you may need sudo)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what SublimeText is, but if it is an app bundle you can do:

`$ open -a SublimeText.app ./My_project/my_example.cpp`

You can do a few other things if you really want it to be exactly the syntax you suggested:

`$ alias sublime='open -a SublimeText.app'`

enter that in a terminal, or add it to your `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Sublime Text 3 via homebrew (cask, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381531/how-to-install-sublime-text-3-using-homebrew)) then it will create `sublime` symlink for you automatically.